# status tag colors with ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I have a status tag in my AA app that only some colors are showing up. Are there certain colors i can use or can't? can't find much information on this.[image]

here is my orders_helper

module OrdersHelper

```
def priority_tag_for_order(order)
  printonrails_status_tag order_priority(order), color_for_weight(order.priority)
  end

  def color_for_weight(weight)
    case weight
      when 'lowest'
        :gray
      when 'low'
        :blue
      when 'mid'
        :yellow
      when 'high'
        :orange
      when 'highest'
        :red
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In the [repo](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin/components/_status_tags.scss) you can see that only a few colours are available, namely green, orange and red.

```css
.status_tag {
  background: darken($secondary-color, 15%);
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.15em;
  padding: 3px 5px 2px 5px;
  font-size: 0.8em;

  &.ok, &.published, &.complete, &.completed, &.green { background: #8daa92; }
  &.warn, &.warning, &.orange { background: #e29b20; }
  &.error, &.errored, &.red { background: #d45f53; }
}
```

If you want to add new ones, you will have to edit your active_admin.css.scss like so

```css
body.active_admin {
  .status_tag.blue { background: #63B8FF; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Luís. I like the CSS methos. Very clean. This document explains the usage of status_tag: http://www.activeadmin.info/docs/12-arbre-components.html#status_tag  In the above question, one can issue status_tag(order.priority) and set the CSS colors for each priority weight.

Comment: Since this post was written, they added `.yes` ( a nice blue) and `.no` (a dark gray). There is also the default light gray.

Comment: 2019, they've removed the colors completely and are now only a yes/no. Copy/Paste above into the .scss to regain it.

Answer (score 2):

We can override ActiveAdmin status_tag (Yes/No) style classes by defining our own style classes inside your `active_admin.scss`. I'm using ruby '2.5.3'. I just wanted to style my Yes/No status_tags in different colors instead of default gray and this worked for me.

```
body.active_admin {
        .status_tag.yes {
                background: #a9c68d;
        }
}

body.active_admin {
        .status_tag.no {
                background: #b3b3b3;
        }
}
```

Now my dashboard looks like this.

[image: I have colored Yes in green and No in gray]

Answer (score 2):

Better to go with custom class approach

```
status_tag 'TAG', class: 'class'
```